# Aluminum wire size needed for new 60 amp garage panel 130' from main 200 amp service in house?

Tags: electrical, wiring

What size aluminum wire for a new 60 amp garage panel to be fed from a 200 amp main service in my house 130' distance?  How many wires?

Comment: Attached or detached garage? And are you running a *cable* or wires in conduit?

Comment: Assuming US/Canada, 4 wires for standard 120/240VAC service. Hot, Hot, Neutral and Ground. Neutral and ground isolated under current code.

Comment: The garage is unattached. The wire run is 30' through he house rafters, then 22' outside the house in conduit, 10' drop into the ground, 50' underground in conduit, and then 8' up from the ground  in conduit and into the new garage panel box.

Comment: If you are running 60A wire and a 60A breaker in the main panel, feel free to upsize to a larger sub-panel, which will give you more breaker spaces.  The 60a breaker will continue to protect the wires, and a 100A sub-panel can obviously handle 60A.  The "main" breaker in the sub-panel can be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Number 4 aluminum is good for 65 amps at 130' the voltage drop at 60 amps would be 2.55% . Up to 3% is allowed by code.